# Edit approved for basically an entirely new answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-answer

I was just trying to solve an Android issue and found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16448278/2141621

Obviously, an Android 8 solution couldn't have been written *in 2013*, so I went to the edit history and it shows this: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16448278/4 
The answer now looks weird, the edit didn't even fix the grammatical errors.

Should the answer be rolled back and, possibly, a community wiki answer be posted instead?

Comment: I think it could be made clearer which part of the answer is for which android version. Other than that there is nothing to be done about now (after more then a year).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The original answer is actually still intact. While posting a separate answer would have been ideal, the fact that it [is a long standing edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380069/1394393) means that removing it is no longer an appropriate course of action.

So we should treat it like any other popular, useful answer that's been put together by several people:

- We should probably community wiki it. This will encourage community edits to improve a popular post that has been poorly maintained by the author, which is in line with [the purpose of Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/).
- Clean up grammar.
- Improve the presentation. Make it more clear what versions of Android each fix applies to. Headers are probably a good idea.
- Add more explanation. The reason why the original change fixes the problem is given in another, unlinked answer. There's no explanation of what the new code block actually does or why it would help, either.

In other words, make it presentable.

---

If the original answer were not still intact, it would be appropriate to edit it back in so that both versions are available. We would still need to clearly distinguish  which versions each solution worked with and explain what changed with the underlying technology. Improving the quality is important as always.

As before, this is because it's a long standing, highly upvoted edit. This approach is not necessarily the best in other cases.

Comment: I am accepting this answer since the original answer was a very low quality one and should be made a community wiki. I have, however, attempted to make the answer a better one

Comment: What would be the purpose of Community Wiki here?

Comment: @RobertHarvey "So we should treat it like any other popular, useful answer **that's been put together by several people**."

Comment: Your logic is a bit circular, but OK.  I'll check with the Teacher's Lounge.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "The intent of community wiki in answers is to help share the burden of solving a question." https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/ That's what has already happened in the cases this Meta question would help us deal with, and in fact, the problems on such posts necessitate even more community intervention. That's the point: to encourage community maintenance by eliminating the "ownership" aspect on a post that hasn't been  well maintained.

Comment: I already CW'd the post.

Answer (score 32):

Two reviewers accepted the review. Imho, that shouldn't have happened.

Usually, I would roll back such edits, but the answer was edited another 2 times since then and gained 100+ upvotes **after** the edit was applied. The optimal thing would have been to add a new answer for Oreo in first place, but that train is gone now.

In theory, we could rollback the edit and copy the edit to a new community wiki answer, but I'm not sure this is really an improvement. The new answer would start with 0 points and would take a long time until it shows up on top.

Comment: So the remaining option would be to copy the original content of the answer to a community wiki answer and provide proper attribution.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Yeah, no.  As BDL pointed out, that ship has already sailed.

Comment: @Robert No BDL said the ship had sailed on moving the _edit_ to its own answer and rolling it back. The ship has most definitely _not_ sailed on moving the _original_ content of the answer to a new answer. That could be done at any point regardless of anything if it were to be determined that the original content of the answer is useful in its own respect.

Comment: @TinyGiant: OK, but why?  In order to turn the world upside-down like this, you need a pretty good justification for doing so.

Comment: For people using the pre-Oreo version. We don't nuke content here just because new versions of software are available. Though this is indeed a bit of a difficult case.

Comment: I find more perplexing that no one has fixed the indentation of that answer! This isn't python where indentation has a meaning other than for reading.

Comment: @Robert if it were to be determined that the original content of the answer is useful in its own respect.

Comment: @TinyGiant I didn't realize this until I looked more closely, either, but the original answer is actually still intact. It just has a giant code block (that seems to lack much explanation) added after it for the updated version of Android.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the answer to remove the wrong content and made it, IMO, more clear.

Comment: @jpmc26 I was speaking in the more general sense of a possible option in situations like this.

Comment: @TinyGiant Good point. I edited my answer to address what we should do in that case.

Comment: Reminds me of what happened to me.. I agree. Cost a lot of upvotes.